# Error in Coherence score in Gensim package

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am getting this error when trying to get the coherence score for topic modelling from Gensim package. The error doesn't seem to be syntax related:

```
    coherence_lda_gens = CoherenceModel(model=lda_gens, 
    texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=dict_lemm, coherence='c_v')
    coherence = coherence_lda_gens.get_coherence()  #this line fails*emphasized text*
    print('\nCoherence Score: ',coherence)
```

and I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\msharifpour\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 172, in get_preparation_data
    main_mod_name = getattr(main_module.__spec__, "name", None)

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'
```

I googled this problem quite a bit, but can't find where the problem comes from and what is the fix?

Thanks